# Mount overlay and assign owner to myuser

Tags: linux, rhel, filesystems, overlayfs

I've an entry in `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
overlay /etc/myfolder    overlay defaults,x-systemd.requires-mounts-for=/var/data,lowerdir=/etc/myfolder,upperdir=/var/data/overlay/myfolder/upper,workdir=/var/data/overlay/myfolder/work 0 2
```

The problem is that `/etc/myfolder` is owned by `root:root` i've tryed `chown myuser:myuser /etc/myfolder` but it return `root:root` at every reboot.
I've also tryed to change the entry in `/etc/fstab` like so:

```
overlay /etc/myfolder    overlay defaults,x-systemd.requires-mounts-for=/var/data,lowerdir=/etc/myfolder,upperdir=/var/data/overlay/myfolder/upper,workdir=/var/data/overlay/myfolder/work,uid=myuser,gid=myuser 0 0
```

but i get this error in dmesg : `overlayfs: unrecognized mount option "uid=994"`

How can mount the overlay ad assign the owner of the folder to `myuser`?
My kernel version is 5.14.0 on RHEL 9.0

Comment: Is `/var/data/overlay/myfolder/upper` located in a filesystem that does not really support Unix-style permissions?